# How to make form inputs interdependent in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, material-ui

I'm practicing to create an app similar to those of peer-2-peer lending, to give a better idea here is a screen.
[Lending Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wz4o.png)

So, loan size and amount represent the same data: the amount of money you want to get. I would like to know how to connect the input amount with the slider, so that the latter moves according to the amount typed and vice versa.
Also I would like the interest rate to increase by a factor of X as the amount requested increases and vice versa.

Form code:

```
......
  <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="size">Loan size</label>
              <Typography id="discrete-slider-always" gutterBottom>
                Min.
              </Typography>
              <Slider
                defaultValue={550}
                min={100}
                max={1000}
                aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
                step={1}
                valueLabelDisplay="on"
              />

              <TextField
                id="standard-read-only-input"
                label="Interest rate"
                defaultValue="25%"
                InputProps={{
                  readOnly: true,
                }}
              />

              <FormControl fullWidth  variant="outlined">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
                <OutlinedInput
                  id="size"
                  name="size"
                  value={tutorial.size}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
                  labelWidth={60}

                />
              </FormControl>

......
```

I hope I was as clear as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
const X_FACTOR = 0.045;

const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(550);

  const handleAmountChange = (value) => {
    setAmount(value);
  };
<Slider
        defaultValue={550}
        min={100}
        max={1000}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
        step={1}
        value={amount}
        onChange={(e, value) => handleAmountChange(value)}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
      />

      <TextField
        id="standard-read-only-input"
        label="Interest rate"
        defaultValue="25%"
        value={`${Math.ceil(amount * X_FACTOR)}%`}
        InputProps={{
          readOnly: true
        }}
      />

      <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          id="size"
          name="size"
          value={amount}
          onChange={(e) => handleAmountChange(e.target.value)}
```

I created a sandbox to show my solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-torvalds-ed2s7?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It works, but how do I set the minimum and maximum value so that in the input box and in the slider they are equal?
In this case min 100 max 1000

Comment: Also I have to keep value = {tutorial.size} otherwise when I submit the form the data is not recorded.

Comment: I updated the sandbox to check the min and max value. Check it out. Now the value of the size input is only updating the tutorial.size on blur, when the user finishes the input.